# How can I get the text that was clicked on in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if it is possible with javascript to to tell the position of a mouse click in some text? I know it's easy to get the x,y coordinates, but I'm wanting the position in the text.

For example if I clicked inside `<p>foo bar</p>`
I want to be able to tell that the click was on/after the 5th character. Or that `foo b` is before the click and `ar` is after it.

By the way, I'm using jQuery too, I'm happy with pure JS and solutions that use jQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to put in a cursor or something? Just curious what the nature of this problem is.

Comment: Yes. I have some editable regions that I can click and type into. I did it this way because I want them to look right in the page. Things like tinyMCE or styled textareas don't stretch to fit content or the page flow like a real `<p>`. It works well, but I'd like to be able to place the cursor in the text rather than just at the end of it.

Comment: Well... Looks like I reinvented the wheel! CONTENTEDITABLE is exactly what I've written, but allows you to click anywhere to move the cursor. Doesn't let me paste into it, but that's alright. Thanks everyone for the creative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript and browsers don't support this directly, but you *could* technically wrap each character in a span and do it based on which span was clicked on:

```
<p>
    <span>f</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span> </span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>r</span>
</p>
```

If anybody actually tries this, be prepared to be eaten by a velociraptor :p

Comment: +1 for velociraptors.  Also, jQuery makes this somewhat easy: `var p = $('p:first'); p.html('<span>' + p.text().split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>');`

Comment: I considered this solution. I had hoped someone here would have one involving less velociraptors

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on codeka's answer and my comment . . . try this (i'm assuming your target `p` has id `my_p`):

```
(function() {
  var p = $('#my_p');
  var o_string = p.text();
  p.html('<span>' + o_string.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>');

  $('span', p).each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('MyIndex', i);
  }).click(function() {
    var char_index = $(this).data('MyIndex');
    if (char_index >= 5) {
      alert('You clicked after character 5!  Before: "' + o_string.substring(0, char_index) + '", After (inclusive): "' + o_string.substring(char_index) + '"');
    }
  });
})();
```

What that does is: 
1. Find the paragraph where you need per-character clicking knowledge, 2. Split the text in that paragraph into a number of one-character spans, 3. Inform each of those one-character spans of its position in the string, and 4. Assign a click() handler to each span, which spits out the information about the span (including your example of char index >= 5, and printing the before and after parts of the string).

Of course you might want to put that in `$(document).ready(...)` instead of an anonymous function; I didn't know if maybe you had a precondition for activating this detection though.

Comment: I don't know if only Jake need is text being clicked, look at my solution below.

Comment: If you read his post, he says this is exactly what he wants . . You are supposed to vote answers down if they're incorrect, not if you disagree with them.

Comment: Thanks Walt W. BTW, you could make this more efficient by binding the click event to #my_p and using event.target to figure out which span was clicked. See http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip12

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I don't like very much idea of travesting text and 'span'ing it. But I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, if you need just the word clicked and do dblclick instead of click will do, i have next code:

```
$('*').dblclick(function(event){
    console.log((window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange().text).toString());
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

after that you can deselect text if you want.
Without toString() you will get object that has a lot of properties, study it as well.

Comment: Thanks vittore. I do need single click, but I'll keep hold of this.